# scipy.optimize.fmin incorrect result shape

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I want to minimize function that takes a matrix whith (3,1) shape as argument.
I use `scipy.optimize.fmin()`. The problem is that function fmin() returns a 1D result with shape (3,). This cause incorrect calculation (problems with dot product etc.) How to solve this problem?

```
theta=np.zeros((3,1))
def sigmoid(x,mytheta):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-np.dot(x,mytheta)))
def costfunction(mytheta,x,y):
    h_xvector=sigmoid(x,mytheta)
    term1=-y*np.log(h_xvector)
    term2=(1-y)*np.log(1-h_xvector)
    J=(1.0/m)*np.sum(term1-term2)
    return J
def optimizeth(mytheta,x,y):
    result=opt.fmin(costfunction,x0=mytheta,args=(x,y),maxiter=400,full_output=True,retall=True)
    return result[0],result[1]
(result, value)=optimizeth(theta,X,Y)
```

X is (100,3) shape matrix, Y is (100,1) shape matrix.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details? A [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: I added code with functions

Comment: *"The problem is that function fmin() returns a 1D result with shape (3,)."*  Why not just reshape the return value to have shape (3,1)?

Comment: It also causes incorrect computation. I make `costfunction()` takes (3,) input as an argument and than inside the function convert it to (3,1) to make correct computation.

Comment: Your code (give or take an import or two and a definition of `m` basically works without error for the input array shapes you give, so unless you provide more detail about what is wrong, with a specific traceback, this question should be closed.

Comment: It doesn't return any error, I obtain values that wasn't expected. I make costfunction() takes (3,) input as an argument and than inside the function convert it to (3,1). Everythink works OK now